# SQL QUERY SELECT Find the time that passed between a fire on a parcel and all fires

Tags: sql

I am trying to understand why we need to select all the following columns

```
SELECT 
    F1.PARCELID, F1.FDATE FIRE1, F2.FDATE, FIRE2,
    F2.FDATE - F1.FDATE INTERVAL
```

as opposed to only this column below. The query in question is below.

```
SELECT F2.FDATE - F1.FDATE INTERVAL
```

Find the time that passed between a fire on a parcel and all fires occurring within 300 days later on the same parcel

```
SELECT 
    F1.PARCELID, F1.FDATE FIRE1, F2.FDATE
    FIRE2,
    F2.FDATE - F1.FDATE INTERVAL
FROM 
    FIRES F1, FIRES F2
WHERE 
    F1.PARCELID = F2.PARCELID
    AND F2.FDATE > F1.FDATE
    AND F2.FDATE <= F1.FDATE + 300;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The select tells you what results you're going to get. The parcel ID, fire dates and time between them sound like reasonable data to want to me, certainly for debugging purposes at least.

Comment: i think i see ok thanks to both